# Replace RxJs errors to prevent completion of action streams

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want my action stream to continue even if there is an error. There for I created a catch and replace observer which replace the error call with an empty observable. Now when there is an error the observable completes its operation immediately  although there is a replacement.

Is there a way yo show the error but let the action stream continue emitting actions?

[The catch and replace code is in my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/replacing-observables-errors?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This is the expected behavior. `catchError` replaces the original observable with the one it has returned. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623868/rxjs-how-to-ignore-an-error-with-catch-and-keep-going

Answer (score 1):

Few approach to keep a stream from completing

Contains your operation in inner Observable:

```
source.pipe(switchMap(x=>
     defer(()=>.... some operation that might throw).pipe(catchError(e=>of(e))))
```

Using repeat() or repeatWhen()

```
source.pipe(catchError(e=>of(e)),repeat())
```

Using retry() - using it with caution, most of the time error will not go away and you end up infinite loop

```
source.pipe(retry())
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs of rxjs: (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)

> In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered, then nothing else can be delivered afterwards.

You can go for `retry` operator or change your Observable to be of type
`Observable<Data | Error>`, distinguish those emissions and handle respectfully.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next({data: 'Some data'});
    }, 7000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next({error: 'Some error message'});
    }, 8000);
```